# Дублирование загружаемой информации в loader

Tags: java, android, android-loader

Загружаю разные списки с фильмами в лоадере + реализовал простой бесконечный скроллинг. Использую `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` для отображения разных списков. Проблема наступает когда начинаю переходить между фрагментами - начинает дублироваться загружаемая информация.
1. Как избежать дублирования информации?(повторного запуска загрузчика)
2. Как весь список загруженого?Так как при повороте сохраняется лишь последняя загруженая информация.

```
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment
                                    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Movie>> {
    private static final String TAG = "MovieFragment";
    private static final String SAVE_CURRENT_PAGE = "current_page";
    private static final int START_POSITION = 1;
    private final int LOADER_ID = 0;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private List<Movie> mMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;
    public int mCurrentPage;
    private LoaderManager mLoaderManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            mCurrentPage = START_POSITION;
        }else {
            mCurrentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVE_CURRENT_PAGE);
        }
        mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        startLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener recyclerViewScrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                mCurrentPage++;
                restartLoading();
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewScrollListener);
        setupAdapter();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SAVE_CURRENT_PAGE, mCurrentPage);
    }

    private void setupAdapter(){
        if (isAdded()){
            mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(mMovies);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        }
    }

    private void startLoading(){
        mLoaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    private void restartLoading(){
        mLoaderManager.restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<Movie>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new  MovieLoader(getActivity, mCurrentPage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Movie>> loader, List<Movie> data) {
        if (data == null || data.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

        mMovies.addAll(data);
        mMovieAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mMovies.size() - 1);

    }

public static class MovieLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Movie>> {

       private int mLoadPage;

        public MovieLoader(Context context, int loadPage) {
            super(context);
        mLoadPage = loadPage;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartLoading(){
            forceLoad();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Movie> loadInBackground() {
            return new FetchMovie.getMovie(mLoadPage);
        }
    }
```

Пример экрана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можеть быть так что метод getMovie возвращает все фильмы от 0 до mCurrentPage?

Comment: @mifkamaz, что вы имеете ввиду?getMovie(int currentPage) возвращает страницу, позже onLoadFinish я добавляю эту страницу к общему листу, который и хранит все фильмы от 0 до n.